# Oracle Apex 20.1 Convert dates on x-axis to dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: oracle-apex, jet

i am struggling to convert the dates on the x-axis to show me the pattern dd.mm.yyy. Currently it shows me yy-mm-dd with a timestamp. I already tried it with to_char(date, 'dd.mm.yyy'), but then the dates get sorted alphabetically on the x-axis. I also tried to change the pattern on the axis settings.

My (dummy) query :

```
select date, to_char(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), value column

from table

where clause

order by trunc(date) asc;
```

Current view:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the x-axis attribute you can change the labels pattern.
[image]